# I want to retrieve the total of amount from particular date which i am giving using Long.what will be query for that in room database

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql, android-room

I want to retrieve the total of amount from a particular date which I am giving using Long.what will be a query for that in room database.here is the query I am written it's not displaying the total amount.

```
@Query("SELECT sum(amount), expense_id, Date FROM EXPENSE Where amount in (SELECT amount FROM Expense WHERE Date BETWEEN :from AND :to)")
List<Expense> expenseBetweenDates(long from, long to);
```

Comment: Remove the WHERE in the outer query and replace it with the WHERE in the inner query and also add proper GROUP BY clause

Comment: can you tell me how

Comment: SELECT sum(amount) ,expense_id ,Date FROM EXPENSE Where Date BETWEEN :from AND :to GROUP BY expense_id, Date)